# Select from db rows as columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this table:

```
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `source_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `initial_price` float(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `sale_price` float(7,2) NOT NULL
```

And my output is like this:

```
<table border="1" class="table">
<thead>
<tr class="border-0">
<th class="border-0">Product name</th>
<th class="border-0">Source ID 1</th>
<th class="border-0">Source ID 2</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
<td>Product 1 name</td>
<td>old_price<br>sale_price of source_id 1</td>
<td>old_price<br>sale_price of source_id 2</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td>Product 2 name</td>
<td>old_price<br>sale_price of source_id 1</td>
<td>old_price<br>sale_price of source_id 2</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td>Product 3 name</td>
<td>old_price<br>sale_price of source_id 1</td>
<td>old_price<br>sale_price of source_id 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

I want to display like this:

```
<table border="1" class="table">
<thead>
<tr class="border-0">
<th class="border-0">Product name</th>
<th class="border-0">Source ID 1</th>
<th class="border-0">Source ID 2</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
<td>Product 1 name</td>
<td>old_price<br>sale_price of source_id 1</td>
<td>old_price<br>sale_price of source_id 1</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td>Product 2 name</td>
<td>old_price<br>sale_price of source_id 2</td>
<td>old_price<br>sale_price of source_id 2</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td>Product 3 name</td>
<td>old_price<br>sale_price of source_id 3</td>
<td>old_price<br>sale_price of source_id 3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

So, all rows from Source ID1 must be columns for Product name 1
all rows from Source ID2 must be columns for Product name 2

Currently I use this SELECT:

```
$products = $db->prepare("SELECT source_id, product_id, 
                                initial_price, sale_price 
                            from products");
```

How need to be my select to output like example from table 2 from snippet?

Comment: You don't show a Product Name in that table ??

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't understand you? What is twice?